# HibernateTemplate returning null

Tags: spring, hibernate, model-view-controller

Hi! here I am trying to use hibernateTemplate in the dao layer, earlier I have working with sessionfactory for retrieving and it worked fine but now I need to implement hibernateTemplate, When I am using hibernateTemplate it is returning null. Here is my dispatcher-servlet.xml and mydao code.

dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties" />
<context:component-scan base-package="net.roseindia" />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager"/>

<bean id="jspViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>net.roseindia.model.Article</value>
            <value>net.roseindia.model.User</value>
            <value>net.roseindia.model.Register</value>
            <value>net.roseindia.model.UserSignup</value>
            <value>net.roseindia.model.BusRequest</value>
            <value>net.roseindia.model.ApprovedRequests</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>             
        </props>
    </property>
 </bean>

   <bean id="hibernateTransactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
   </bean>
</beans>
```

and my dao file is

```
package net.roseindia.dao;

import java.util.List;

import net.roseindia.model.ApprovedRequests;
import net.roseindia.model.BusRequest;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository("busRequestDao")
public class BusRequestDaoImpl implements BusRequestDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory)
    {
        this.hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
    }

    @Override
    public void addRequest(BusRequest busrequest) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(busrequest);

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<BusRequest> listrequests() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return (List<BusRequest>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(BusRequest.class).list();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<ApprovedRequests> listApprovedrequests() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //  return (List<ApprovedRequests>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(ApprovedRequests.class).list();
         return hibernateTemplate.find("from ApprovedRequests");
    }


    @Override
    public void approveRequest(ApprovedRequests approvedRequests) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(approvedRequests);
    }

}
```

In the above dao file for listApprovedrequests method i have tried hibernateTemplate but it is returning null. I have also used `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(ApprovedRequests.class).list()`(commented one) its working fine but unable to work with hibernatetemplate  dont know where i am going wrong can anybody help me how to achieve this??

Comment: Why do you want to use HibernateTemplate? Its own documentation advises against its usage, and suggests using the hibernate API directly. It doesn't even exist anymore for Hibernate 4. That said, HibernateTemplate.find() never returns null. Your diagnostic is wrong, and some other code is transforming the list it returns to null.

Comment: I presume that hibernateTemplate is itself null within the method. This is because you use field injection. Move `@Autowired` over setter, thus your template will be initialized. Anyway, as noted, avoid using `HibernateTemplate`

Comment: @orid: I didn't get you exactly can you explain me some elaborately how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory)
{
    this.hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
}
```

with

```
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

@Autowired
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory)
{
    this.hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
}
```